# A and B are 99% correlated. C is highly correlated with A. Should C be also equally correlated with B?

Tags: correlation, inference

I have a simple correlation question: there are three variables, A, B, C.

A and B are 99% correlated.

C is 95% correlated with A. But it is only 88% correlated with B.

Is this unusual? Should C be almost equally correlated with both A and B? If not, what is the maximum difference in correlations that we can expect?

Comment: The correlations you describe are mathematically impossible, according to the criteria in the duplicate: but if we interpret them as values rounded to the nearest percent, then (say) they could theoretically equal 98.6%, 94.6%, and 88.4%.

Comment: @whuber thanks so much for your reply. Would you mind elaborating a bit more on what you mean? Why are they mathematically impossible?

Comment: My answer in the duplicate gives a numerical criterion for three mutual correlations $(\rho,\sigma,\tau)$ to be possible: namely, $1 + 2 \rho \sigma \tau - \left(\rho^2 + \sigma^2 + \tau^2\right) \ge 0.$  When I apply it to your three numbers, it shows your matrix has a negative determinant, which is not possible for any correlation matrix.

Comment: Are you using pairwise deletion of missing values with those sample correlations? You may get inconsistent sets of correlations that way (ones that don't form a positive semi-definite correlation matrix).

Comment: Thank you so much y'all! That really did solve the problem.